# How can I add depth to a shape

Tags: android

I need to make my EditText look like its got depth like in the image below.

I have this shape I don't know what to add to it

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="50dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/primary_dark" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: In short: I'd use a **9 patch**. Mind that, since it is still a **png** image, you can play with transparencies and make **a single image** which will work on **every** background color.

Comment: @DerGolem can you please explain further what you mean by since it png...

Comment: PNG image pixels can have 256 levels of transparency (ALPHA channel). So, it's easy to create a desaturated version of yout picture, set the overall opacity to... say 25%. Then delete the outside part, leaving the frame completely transparent. Then make a 9 patch out of it, as illustrated here: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/. DONE!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can accomplish that with a `drawable` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--background to compensate the transparency under shadow and glow (for bigger depth values)-->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/primary_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--top, dark, inner shadow-->
    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/depth">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#1A000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--bottom, light, outer glow-->
    <item
        android:top="@dimen/depth">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#4DFFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--your color-->
    <item
        android:top="@dimen/depth"
        android:bottom="@dimen/depth">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/primary_dark />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and define a `dimen` in `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="depth">2dp</dimen>
```

by changing of the `dimen` you can change the depth of the `drawable`

Answer (score 3):

This might also make your field look close to the effect but with a little more depth (see below).  It might be worth adding the background to a outer view to wrap the edit text too so you can indent the text if you haven't already done this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- outer shine -->
    <item
        android:top="4dp"
        android:left="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#1597FB" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- inner shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#004173" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- inner background -->
    <item
        android:top="2dp"
        android:left="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#006EC3" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And then you EditText as below;

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_layered_combined">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</FrameLayout>
```